# Converging or diverging but how?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I faced this question about if $\sum A_n$ while $k > 1$ & $k < 1$ is diverging or converging where $A_n = \left(1- \dfrac{\log n + k\log\log n}{n}\right)^n$; although I could see that whenever K is greater than 1 then $A_n$ is decreasing and while K is lesser 1 then $A_n$ is increasing but how do I prove this ?

Comment: You should probably change the title to make it more meaningful and descriptions of the question

Comment: It seems to me that this should always converge: eventually $0<\frac{\log n + k \log \log n}{n}<1/2$ and then you can compare to the geometric series. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ian But $1-(\log n+k\log\log n)/n\to1$.

Comment: So "yes", I was. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
A_n&=\Biggl(\Bigl(1- \frac{\log n + k\log\log n}{n}\Bigr)^{\frac{n}{\log n + k\log\log n}}\Biggr)^{\log n + k\log\log n}\\
&\sim e^{-\log n + k\log\log n}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}(\log n)^k.
\end{align}$$